# can i join table 1 column with table 2 row?

Tags: sql

If I have 2 table like this :

TABLE 1

```
id    |    u1    |    u2    |     u3      |     u4
---------------------------------------------------
1     |   abc1   |   abc1   |    abc2     | null
```

TABLE 2

```
id    |  name
--------------
abc1  |  dallas

abc2  | erika
```

Can I get  the join function result like this??? :

```
X     |    Y    |   Z
----------------------
u1    |    abc1 |   dallas

u2    |    abc1 |   dallas

u3    |    abc2 |   erika

u4    |   NULL  |  NULL
```

Comment: what database are you using ? Please do not spam the tag

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially How to [Ask], and [edit] your question accordingly. It's very rare that people need a solution that works with all the different databases you've tagged. Please either use the database-agnostic tag or the tag for the specific database product you are using (as well as it's specific version tag).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using union all and left join

```
select * from
(
select 'u1' as id,u1 as uname from table1
union all
select 'u2',u2 from table1
union all
select 'u3',u3 from table1
union all
select 'u4',u4 from table1
) A left join table2 B on a.uname=b.id
```

Comment: what is A and B on the last??

Comment: @FazzLeighlan it's the table alias name

Comment: if i have two data in table1 with id is 1 and 2,  how can i search for data with table1.id = 2 if i use query like your answer??

Comment: if i have two data in table1 with id is 1 and 2, how can i search for data with table1.id = 2 if i use query like your answer??

Comment: just use where clause @FazzLeighlan